# FlashDevelop startup problems - problems with plugins

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

When starting up FlashDevelop version 5.3.3.1 for .NET 4.0 on my Windows 10 system I'm getting these messages:

> Unable to load an incompatible or broken plugin: C:\Program Files(x86)\FlashDevelop\Plugins\jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.4.0.dll

and

> Unable to load an incompatible or broken plugin: C:\Program Files(x86)\FlashDevelop\Plugins\LoomContext.dll

Once I select OK on both notifications the program seems to run and build without issue.

Now it's been a couple months since I ran this program on this Windows 10 system but I don't remember there being a problem until now.

Reinstalling FlashDevelop did not fix it.

I tried simply removing these files from the `\Plugins` folder and now it starts up without the error notifications and seems to run fine but I'm concerned that there are unseen problems because of these plugin problems.

Anyone have any special insight on why these two plugin files would suddenly be giving me problems?

Comment: With jni4net, I have found (with a very brief search) that you might need JRE matching OS bitness (64-bit, that is) for that plugin to work, and since it's in x86 folder, *maybe* 32-bit Java is also required. Also those plugins were designed for older Windows versions, so Windows 10 can enforce incompatibilities as well. Try running FD with compatibility mode set to W7 or lower with both plugin DLLs present.